# Выводит одну и туже ссылку к каждому заголовку, selenium pyrhon

Tags: python, selenium

Задача такая: на открывшейся вкладке подбираем все заголовки и подбираем ссылку на каждый заголовок. Проблема с выводом, заголовок отображается правильно, но ссылка на заголовок показывает везде одинаковая.

```py
all_window = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'LC20lb.MBeuO.DKV0Md')
links = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'yuRUbf').find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'a').get_attribute('href')# выводит ссылку элемента
    for i in range(len(all_window)):
        print(all_window[i].text,links)
```

Comment: Вывод такой, а нужно разные ссылки
ГМО - последние новости сегодня https://ria.ru/keyword_GMO_2/
ГМО — последние новости сегодня на РБК.Ру https://ria.ru/keyword_GMO_2/
ГМО – новости и статьи по тегу | Forbes.ru https://ria.ru/keyword_GMO_2/

Comment: У вас links в цикле не менят значенния. Как задали значение перед циклом так и остаеться.

Comment: А как правильно сделать?

Comment: еще если задаю так 
link = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".yuRUbf a").get_attribute('href')
for i in range(len(link):
    print(link[i])
ошибка AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'

Comment: Селениюм не мой конек, я больше по BeautifulSoup. Если all_window у нас имеет тип list, судя по коду, значить и links имеет токой же тип.  То нам надо перебрать все индексы all_window и links print(all_window[i].text,links[i])

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему с помощью BeautifulSoup

```py
for p in range(11):#Бежим по страничкам
    soup = BS(driver.page_source,'lxml')
    orgs = soup.findAll('div', class_='')
    for org in orgs:#на страничках добавляем данные(Заголовок, ссылка)
        name = org.find('h3',class_='').text # поиск заголовков
        link = org.find('div',class_='').find('a').get('href')#поиск ссылок
        data.append([name,link])#добавляем в словарь
    button_next = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'').click()# Кнопка следующая
    sleep(3)
```